# TCP Server to Receive Commands on Port 211

Tags: objective-c, delphi, tcp

I'm creating a Delphi server using some of the DataSnap server components and listening on port 211. I want to pass commands (e.g. "exec sp_something or other") from Objective-C on the iPad, and return a JSON result string. Can someone get me started on this one ? I have been doing Delphi since 1995 but I am new to Obj-C. Therein lies the problem. Creating the data server was a snap, writing the Obj-C has me puzzled, both to send the command and receive the JSON result. Parsing the JSON is no big deal. I just need to get it first !
TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You can't listen on port 211;  ports below 1024 are reserved for root owned processes.

You'll really want to start with an intro to Objective-C guide of some sort.  Given your history, you can probably get away with just reading [Apple's excellent guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) without bothering with the tutorials.

From there, you'll need to understand how to write iOS applications.  Again, the [Apple guide is a good start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but you might consider any of a number of 3rd party tutorials or guides.

Thinking of this learning exercise as answering the question "what lines of code do I need to write?" is a sure fire recipe to failure.   You really need to understand the architecture of iOS applications and how your Objective-C code fits within.